# curl and xmllint pipe

Tags: xml, curl, xmllint

I try to pipe curl and xmllint to parse the xml output from an url. But for some reason xml won't parse the xml and instead the resulting xml from the curl is shown. 
I'm a missing a setting?
If is store the result of the curl action as a file and use that as an input for xmllint it parses correctly.

```
 curl --location --header "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://www.test.com | xmllint --format - --xpath '//title'
```

Comment: Perhaps it prints to stderr and you need `2>&1`? Or you could use my [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) `http://www.test.com -e //title ` then you do not need to pipe

Answer (score 67):

Seems that `xmllint` requires the `-` stdin redirect be at the end of the command.

```
curl --location --header "Accept: application/rdf+xml" http://www.test.com \
  | xmllint --format --xpath '//title' -
```

Comment: how to separate results with newline

Comment: This is almost a convention to use `-` to represent a file read from stdin.

Answer (score 12):

more succinct

```
curl foo.com/somefile.xml | xmllint --format -
```

Explanation:

Here we are [piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) the xml from the curl command into the xmllint command. The xmllint man page says

```
$ man xmllint
> ... The xmllint program parses one or more XML files, specified on the command line as XML-FILE (or the standard input if the filename provided is - ).
```

So that's why we do `xmllint --format -` because this particular command will read from stdin if you specify `-` as the filename. Sidenote, there's a discussion about the `-` arg [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2007-February/msg00006.html). I personally don't like that stdin is not the default but I'm not the author.

Comment: I added an  explanation. Even though I wanted to provided a short answer.

Comment: Also save file locally `curl foo.com/file.xml | xmllint --format - > file.xml` thanks